# Filter tab to categorize data table's content?

Tags: usability, tables, tabs, sort, filter

Any UX issue for using filter tab to wrap the entire data table so it separates (but not eliminate) one category from the entire group.

**Example:** Objects that has different status such as "Pending" "Processing" "Completed" Since user only look at/care about "Pending" objects - there will be 2 filter tab that group "Pending" and "All" (which contain the entire object, including pending). This way, instead of using a status filter dropdown, the result are immediately shown to user. Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I don't really see a question here, rather I read two different methods to show/separate content. Could you be more specific in what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding filter drop down would be the better option

1. It is scalable and flexible
2. If the records are more than 50, this suits better
3. If user's primary attention is Status field the add better visual treatment
4. Inline filter also good option

Adding additional 'pending' tab for filter not better option

1. If the records are more, then user has to wait for loading another tab
2. Data column is same in both the tab
3. In this page there are 2 sets of table data is repeating on two tabs
4. In the feature if functionality demands then need to add some more tab
5. Additional implementation effort